# Batch команда для запуска программы с определенными графическими процессорами

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, bat

У меня имеется 2 граф. проц. и eсть батч файл который запускает мою программу. Возникают некоторые проблемы и хотелось бы добавить линию, где описано через какой граф. проц. запускать программу.

Comment: Добавляйте. А кто или что мешает? Рекомендую прочесть эту [статью](https://www.trishtech.com/2018/12/how-to-set-graphics-performance-preference-for-apps-in-windows-10/). Написать скрипт, привязывающий приложение к тому или иному GPU, зная некоторые тонкости конфигурации, - можно.

Comment: @Daemon-5 какой вы умный человек

Comment: Чувствую иронию. Однако Вы опробовали предложенный способ - он неприемлем, не соответствует архитектуре, иное?